# How to clone AWS service configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services

My current project is depending hard on AWS, using different services: SQS, Lambda, DynamoDB, S3, API gateway ... and they interact with each other to perform a specific task (for example, a sqs trigger a lambda and store processed data to dynamodb and s3). After deploying and testing, all are working together very well, I am planning to clone the current working environment for a new project.

The normal way I can think of is creating new services one by one (because I took note all configurations for each service so far)

My question: Is there any good and automatical way to clone the working AWS environment configuration?

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Comment: Check out CloudFormation.

Comment: You are looking for an Infrastructure as Code tool, either CloudFormation or Terraform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CloudFormation template to design your architecture and then reuse it as needed.

Since you already have your architecture running, instead of doing it manually, you can run CloudFormer which will allow you create CloudFormation template out of your existing infrastructure. You can pick which parts to include in CloudFormation template via web interface and once done, you can launch another such architecture via that newly created CloudFormation template.